# best way to react on substring out of bounds exception

Tags: java, string, exception

While parsing internet content of HTML pages there is common thing that due to mistakes in HTML code some chars are absent - for example closing " or > or something else. And when a parser meet this situation sometimes it occurs "out of bounds exception". I am thinking about the best way to work around this issue - try\catch is good but slow enough. A series of if/else perhaps would be better but may be you know some mechanism that allow to skip this abnormal situations?

Comment: **try\catch is good but slow enough** I don't quite agree with it. Internally jdk code checks some condition (using `if` and `else`) and throws these errors/exception

Comment: @sanbhat I think he is refering to the slowness of exception throwing - throwing an exception is inherently expensive.

Comment: Yes, RB - you are right

Comment: Well, how would you like to deal with a page that wasn't valid? Not throw errors? How would you parse it then?

Comment: I think the best way is just skip this page - this is the most quick variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use an `if else` chain, testing for each necessary char at a time. A while loop could probably also used to do this. Those are the best two I know of.

To test if a char exists with Strings, use the following tests

```
int exists = s.indexOf('<'); //Or any char
int close = s.lastIndexOf('>'); //Or other pair of char

if (exists != -1 && close != -1) { //Could be modified depending on the situation
    //Perform logic
}
```

To test for '"'s, or any other identical braces I would do this

```
int exists = s.indexOf('"'); 
int close = s.lastIndexOf('"');

if (exists != close || (exists != -1 && close != -1) {
    //Perform logic
}
```